# Is it possible to play a gapless looped WAV file without stuttering?

Tags: audio, wav, blackberry-10, openal, qnx

I have a requirement for perfect gapless looped audio in a BlackBerry 10 app. My loops are stored as WAV files. The method I'm using for playing them is:

1. Create a buffer for the WAV file using `alutCreateBufferFromFile` which returns a `bufferID`
2. Create a sound source using `alGenSources`
3. Attach the buffer to the source using `alSourcei(source, AL_BUFFER, bufferID)`
4. Set the source looping property to true using `alSourcei(source, AL_LOOPING, AL_TRUE)`
5. Play the source using `alSourcePlay(source)`

The audio plays fine *most* of the time, but during UI transitions (such as when the backlight goes off, or when the app is minimised) the audio stutters.

Any ideas how I can ensure the audio is smooth the whole time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How do you run a thread/process playing WAV file? Have you had a chance to play around priorities and policies with that thread?

I think these low-level system calls allowing to change process (thread, actually) priority and policy might help:

- [pthread_setschedprio](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/p/pthread_setschedprio.html)
- [pthread_setschedparam](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/reference/bb10/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.lib_ref/topic/p/pthread_setschedparam.html)

Also, have a look at respective doc pages:

- [BB10 Priorities](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.getting_started/topic/s1_procs_priorities.html)
- [BB10 Scheduling policies](https://developer.blackberry.com/native/documentation/bb10/com.qnx.doc.neutrino.sys_arch/topic/kernel_schedulingalgorithms.html)
- [QNX Neutrino MicroKernel](http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/sys_arch/kernel.html#SCHEDULING)

I'd start with setting policy to FIFO and raise priority of the process playing audio file. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks, those are some handy hints. When I call `alSourcePlay` it spawns a separate thread to do the playing. How can I change the priority of that thread, rather than my main thread?

Comment: I've set the scheduling policy of my main thread to FIFO and upped the thread priority to 63 (the highest permissible for non-root apps) my theory being that the child process which plays the audio will inherit those properties. Unfortunately the stuttering still occurs. Any suggestions?

Comment: OK, I figured it out. The thread priority must be set prior to initialising anything to do with OpenAL, then it works like a charm. Thanks very much!